# Can I block ChromeDriver to connect certain websites? When using Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to block c# controlled Google ChromeDriver via Selenium

Is that possible?

This is how i start the selenium and navigate

```
var Driver = new ChromeDriver();
Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(URL)
```

Lets say i want that particular Chrome instance to do not connect `http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net:443`

Is this possible?

When that chrome instance requests to connect `http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net:443`, it should be automatically blocked or maybe return `127.0.0.1` I do not know

I need some solution which will prevent driver waiting response

Ok after i saw the answer i think i couldnt clarify the question well enough

The thing i want is, i am navigating to a page, which makes a lot of unnecessary requests to other hosts. I want to block those hosts, so page load timings would be much better

I tried via editing hosts file in etc and now it is 10 times better

But this is system wide

I wonder same may apply to chromedriver or not

Comment: If Selenium doesn't have any pre-build functions I guess your only solution would be to create a timer (System.Timers.Timer) that checks if the current URL should be blocked, and if it is, tell the driver to go backwards or something like that.

Comment: ty for the answer. i have updated my question.

Comment: Not sure how this will work, but i'm thinking about this solution - inject JS and use JQuery's [Global Ajax Event Handlers](https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/) to handle request events. Apply filter with `.ajaxSend()` on the hosts u need to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The WebDriver does not allow this level of control (on purpose), so the short answer is no, you can't do that through it.

There is a solution though - just proxy all the traffic, and blacklist the offending URIs; or whitelist the one you're working with. In any ways, make the proxy return a reasonable response in time (a pixel file, or 404) for any unneeded URIs.
Sample code (my C#is rusty :):

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("--proxy-server=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX");
var Driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

(for Firefox it's a bit different, it's set as capabilities there)

There are a lot of options for the proxy, from the [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org) legend, the [tinyproxy](https://tinyproxy.github.io) I've used in the past for similar purposes, to [whatever](https://www.google.com/search?q=simple%20proxy%20server) will suit your environment and needs.

Comment: seems like a lot of hassle. i wish browser were supporting it